# Add className to image in kineticjs

Tags: javascript, image, class, kineticjs

I want to add class name to image. Is it correct? can anyone tell?

```
var image = new Kinetic.Image({
    name: data,
    id: "image"+(imageCount++),
    x: 10,
    y: 10,
    image: theImage,
    className:"group",
    draggable: false
});
```

Comment: Would you be able to say what the 'theImage' variable is referring to?

Comment: @rwacarter just variable.i'm asking adding class name is correct or not

Comment: Why do you need class name for image? Styles can not be applied with canvas.

Answer (score 0):

This should add the class to the image (assuming 'theImage' is a reference to the image DOM element):

```
var image = new Kinetic.Image({
    name: data,
    id: "image"+(imageCount++),
    x: 10,
    y: 10,
    image: theImage,
    draggable: false
});

theImage.className += ' group';
```